# if theres no record display in datagridview then messagebox no member found

Tags: vb.net

im using datagridview to display employee details and when theres no record found there will be a messagebox that there were no record found here's my code.

```
     Dim search As String = String.Empty
    search &= "select * from record "
    search &= "where identification=@identification;"

    Using conn As New SqlConnection("server=KENJOY_FMCD;database=humanresource;user=ayala747;password=4525422;")
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand()
            With cmd
                .Connection = conn
                .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                .CommandText = search
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@identification", vsearch.Text)
            End With
            Try
                conn.Open()
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                Dim ds As New DataSet
                da.Fill(ds)

                If ds.Tables.Count >= 0 Then
                    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
                End If
                If (ds Is Nothing) Then
                    MsgBox("No record found!")
                End If
                conn.Close()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You created a local dataset, so why check it for nothing?  Check the number of rows in the table in the DS.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: It's not just IF-ENDIF, there is also IF-ELSE-ENDIF.  Users don't like unnecessary message boxes.

Comment: i try the if else end if statement but still the messagebox for record not found is not  showing up

Comment: Tables and Records are two different things.  Your IF is looking at how many tables, which with your code should always be one.

Comment: The status bar was made for this sort of communication